# TinyMce & Database - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008-r2, tinymce

It's there a possibility to save images added to TinyMce content into a database ( sql server  table) ?

Let's say we have like this : text text IMAGE text text IMAGE2  ( IMAGE & IMAGE2 were added with an image uploader plugin ) . Maybe using something like HttpPostedFileBase. I don't know, I am kinda newbie.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the images on your server, you can now take your tinymce content and replace the images serverside with its base64 encoded string - then you write all to your db.

Comment: The images I am adding to tinyMce are in my HDD. I'm sending back to the controller the content of the editor, but how can I verify what is image and what is not ?  I'm saving the content in a table, but separately I want to save images on another table.

Comment: just one other point: it might be more effective/faster to just save the file_path to your database and keep the images in an image directory on your server hd

Comment: I understand, thank you, but this is the requirement.  Look what I am trying to do:                                                                 List<Uri> links = new List<Uri>();
           string matchString = "<img.+?src=[&quot;](.+?)[&quot;].+?>";
           MatchCollection matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(Content, matchString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
           foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
           {
               string href = m.Groups[1].Value;
               links.Add(new Uri(href));
           } But it doesn't work

Comment: sry, i am not familiar with asp.net